# How to handle tap on cta's of showTimePicker

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using showTimePicker to show time picker dialog and I want to handle tapping of ok button in dialog not sure how to do that

- I want to check on tapping if the current time is less than selected time and show message according to that

OR

- Limit the time selection in dialog itself upto a certain time (Don't want to use plugin)

```
showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
      helpText: StringElements.selectTxnTime,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
              primary: Variables.cashBaseColor,
            ),
          ),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

first, add this line

```
TimeOfDay picker;
```

then

```
picker = showTimePicker(
  context: context,
  initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
  helpText: StringElements.selectTxnTime,
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
          primary: Variables.cashBaseColor,
        ),
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  },
),
```

now you can access desired time hour and minute with

```
picker.hour;
picker.minute;
```

now use this line to get the current time

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
now.hour; 
now.minute;
```

now you should just compare these two.

Comment: I want to handle on ok button of that time picker dialog don't want to compare after selection